# Pull average (or not) based on date

Tags: r, reformatting

[image: picture of data]

I am trying to get R to pull the value for "reading" if the "daily date" is in between the "start date" and "end date." If the "daily date" is in between two intervals (so the "end date" of one line and the "start date" of another), I want it to take the average of the readings. You can see this in the "daily reading column) Most of the reading periods are 2 days but sometimes not, so I want to make sure that is taken into account. I am still new to R, so I understand if the current format is not the best to do this! My inputs are: "start date", "end date" "reading" "reading period" and I want "daily date" and "daily reading" as outputs. Thanks!

```
structure(list(`Start Date` = structure(c(1193961600, 1194134400, 
1194307200, 1194480000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `End Date` = structure(c(1194134400, 
1194307200, 1194480000, 1194998400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Reading = c(3, 
4, 3.5, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `reading period` = c(2, 
2, 2, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Daily Date` = structure(c(1194048000, 
1194134400, 1194220800, 1194307200, 1194393600, 1194480000, 1194566400, 
1194652800, 1194739200, 1194825600, 1194912000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Daily reading` = c(3, 3.5, 4, 3.75, 
3.5, 2.75, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: "I want it to take the average of the readings", the average over what ? THe whole column Reading ?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I edited the post to show what dput outputs

Comment: @Julien I want it to take the average value of reading when the date is in 2 periods. For example, 11/4/2007 should be the average reading in line 1 and line 2 because 11/4/2007 shows up in line 1 and 2.

Comment: If feels like you have two separate data frames stuck together for no reason. My best guess is that you start with one `Daily` data frame with columns `Daily Date` and `Daily Reading`, and a second data frame `Periods` with columns `Start Date` and `End Date` indicating periods to average. And then the goal would be to get the appropriate `Daily Reading` values from the `Daily` data frame and average them, putting the averages in a new `Average Reading` column in the `Period` data frame.

Comment: @GregorThomas. That makes sense to have it as two separate data frames. Not every daily reading is an average thought it's only an average if the date spans two periods. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this is what you want. I start with only the period columns, and I construct everything else from there. Your picture excludes the first and last `Daily Date` values. I left them in, but if you want to get rid of them you can add `%>% slice(-c(1, n())` to the end of the code to drop the first and last rows.

```
library(dplyr)
# pull out the period data
period = df %>% select(`Start Date`, `End Date`, Reading, `reading period`)

# make a daily data frame based on period data
daily = data.frame(
  `Daily Date` = seq.Date(
    from = as.Date(min(period$`Start Date`)),
    to = as.Date(max(period$`End Date`)), 
    by = "1 day"
  ), check.names = FALSE
)

# join, filter, and average
daily %>%
  full_join(period, by = character()) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date"), as.Date)) %>%
  filter(
    `Start Date` <= `Daily Date` & `Daily Date` <= `End Date`
  ) %>%
  group_by(`Daily Date`) %>%
  summarize(`Daily reading` = mean(Reading))
# # A tibble: 13 × 2
#    `Daily Date` `Daily reading`
#    <date>                 <dbl>
#  1 2007-11-02              3   
#  2 2007-11-03              3   
#  3 2007-11-04              3.5 
#  4 2007-11-05              4   
#  5 2007-11-06              3.75
#  6 2007-11-07              3.5 
#  7 2007-11-08              2.75
#  8 2007-11-09              2   
#  9 2007-11-10              2   
# 10 2007-11-11              2   
# 11 2007-11-12              2   
# 12 2007-11-13              2   
# 13 2007-11-14              2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error trying to make the dataframe: Error in period$`Start Date` : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Make sure you replace `df` in my code with whatever the name of your actual data frame is.